# Apply fix value difference in selected pixels of a raster file in Qgis

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, editing, select

I am using the serval plugin in QGIS to spot edit a DEM in raster format. Besides the built in tools that I use,  I have realized that in some cases I can achieve the desired results by applying a fixed difference in the cell values of a specific area.

What expression can I use in order to aquire the cell values in the area that I have selected with serval and then subtract or add a specific value?